# (osx) cannot download self signed cert

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, terminal, ssl-certificate

I have a series of intranet self signed certs.  I've been able to download most with Firefox but there's one in particular that's giving me trouble.  There's no option in Firefox to 'view' the cert and export it.  I just get this message:

> An error occurred during a connection to URL:PORT. SSL peer cannot
>   verify your certificate. Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_ALERT
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

I also tried this command:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect URL:HOST | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ./$SERVERNAME.cert
```

And I get this error:

> verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
>   verify return:0

I'm well aware of what im trying to connect to and the risks involved - how do I get the certs?